# IronPython: adding references from host application

Tags: c#, ironpython

In my application I'm using Iron Python to provide scripting capabilities. The problem is that embedded scripts don't see references I've linked to the app. Only solution as I understand is to manually import them from script

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(...)
from ... import ...
```

but I'm reading scripts from files and I don't want to prepend a bunch of imports like this.
So how do I add references from host application? ScriptEngine / ScriptScope doesn't look to have any related methods :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method you want is `ScriptRuntime.LoadAssembly`, easily accessed from your ScriptEngine instance:

```
engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(typeof(System.Web.HttpContext).Assembly);
```

Comment: thank you! somewhy i didn't guess to look into runtime of the engine